# How do I make a very basic file filter using grep?

Tags: macos, unix, search, filter, grep

A really simple question, but I couldn't find a simple answer here on SO.

I have a log file `my.log` where some lines contain the word "User". How can I make a grep command to run constantly and output every time the log is updated with a line containing the word "User"? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tail -f my.log | grep User
```

tail -f watches the file and outputs any lines added to the end

Answer (score 2):

You're right, it's  simple:

```
tail -f my.log | grep "User"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry I can't choose them all as accepted.

Comment: @nevan: In doubt just choose the first answer.